# Getting "is not a thenable" message while using "eventually" in protractor chai

Tags: protractor, cucumber, chai, cucumberjs

When I tried to verify the condition as below.

```
 var val1 = "ONE";
 var val2 = "TWO";
 expect(val1==val2).to.eventually.equal(false)
```

I'm getting **false is not a thenable** message, If I removed **eventually** condition as below then it working fine.

```
 var val1 = "ONE";
 var val2 = "TWO";
 expect(val1==val2).to.equal(false)
```

Can anyone help me to understand the difference. Also If the condition fails, It displays the error message and not executing the **hooks.js**.

Answer (score 13):

In simple words:

`eventually` - is a method from chai-as-promised.
If you use `eventually` protractor expects that you are asserting result of a promise to value (in this case `false`).
`val1` and `val2` are bools. Comparison of `val1` and `val2` is also a bool.

Bool is not a promise.

You've got two possibilities:
1. Don't use eventually (just a chai).
2. Return a promise from comparison of those values.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But one doubt if my bool assertion got failed   it throws as error message and abruptly stops the feature file executions without passing the scenarios as failed.

Comment: Do you use the cucumber framework? I had this problem solved setting ignoreUnhandledExceptions: true in the config file as described here : https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework.