# Assertion error in protractor using getText()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, chai, cucumberjs

I am trying to check the value of three dropdown boxes using BDD and Protractor.

The code related to this is:

```
checkDropdown: function (value, dropdown) {
    let name = element(by.id(dropdown));
    console.log(name.getText());
    expect(name.getText()).to.equal(value);
},
```

And the output is:

```
       AssertionError: expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to equal 'Apparent Energy'
```

How can I do to make it works? I thought that getText should retrieves a string instead of an object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: output of console.log(name.getText());?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are asserting a promise, just change the code like below to wait for the promise,

```
checkDropdown: function (value, dropdown) {
   element(by.id(dropdown)).then(function(elem){
     elem.getText().then(function(text) {
        expect(text).to.equal(value);
     })
   });   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`expect(name.getText()).to.eventually.equal(value);`

See here:
[Getting "is not a thenable" message while using "eventually" in protractor chai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900889/getting-is-not-a-thenable-message-while-using-eventually-in-protractor-chai/44902668#44902668)